# CSS background half on either side?

Tags: css, background, background-image

In the inferno design (SMF 2.0), the red background of the main_body div shows up half on the left and half on the right, how is this done? http://demo.dzinerstudio.com/

Comment: i cant see the red background... or is it just very late!

Comment: sorry just needed to change the layout in the dropdowns at the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a background image on the body element that is aligned top and tiled horizontally.

```
body {
  background: url(/myimage.png) center top repeat-x
}
```

then just need the image to be the right height for the look your going for...

Answer (score 0):

It's just because the div.wrapper is on top of the div.main_body. To get the half effect on the main_body div, they just have a background color and a gradient image tiled on the x axis. 
Is that not you question?